# Getting access denied while running invoke command ,kerberos dula hop delegation authentication error

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Hi I am getting below access denied error while accessing file remotely even though I have access to shared location .Kerberos credential delegation is enabled

```
PS C:\Users> $uname = "abrac\svc-igniopro-connect"
$password = "P@er***" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $uname,$password
Invoke-Command -ComputerName EABP01IGCHEA01 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "\\Ebrfile01\tcs\IT\INFRA IGNIO SOX\vdi NS list 1.csv"}
Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\Ebrfile01\tcs...i NS list 1.csv:String) [Get-Content], UnauthorizedAccessExceptio 
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : EABP01IGCHEA01
 
Cannot find path '\\Ebrfile01\tcs\IT\INFRA IGNIO SOX\vdi NS list 1.csv' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\Ebrfile01\tcs...i NS list 1.csv:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : EABP01IGCHEA01
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `CredSSP` (see: [Enable-WSManCredSSP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/enable-wsmancredssp)) on both the client and server (necessary for this double hop authentication).

First enable on your client to server direction by running this on your machine:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role "Client" -DelegateComputer "EABP01IGCHEA01"
```

Then on your server `EABP01IGCHEA01`, enable the Server role so that it can act as a delegate:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role "Server"
```

Then you have to explicitly specify the authentication method as `CredSSP` as it won't connect with it by default:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName EABP01IGCHEA01 -Authentication Credssp -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "\\Ebrfile01\tcs\IT\INFRA IGNIO SOX\vdi NS list 1.csv"}
```

Please note the [security implications of enabling CredSSP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/enable-wsmancredssp):

> Caution:
>
> CredSSP authentication delegates the user credentials from the local
> computer to a remote computer. This practice increases the security
> risk of the remote operation. If the remote computer is compromised,
> when credentials are passed to it, the credentials can be used to
> control the network session.

Comment: The problem is I cannot use credssp because of some restriction in tool.

I have one server where I can run this invoke command to get folder content easily after just enabling keberos delegation .

But from the server where I want is not working ..I have checked all settings and everything are same ..Not able to identify what is causing this access denied error